# Changing bash terminal color and setting it back to default?

Tags: bash, bashrc, colors

I found this command to change the background color to back:

```
echo -ne '\e]11;#000000\e\\'
```

So, how to I make it to change the default again?

Thanks :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to replace the #000000 with the color of your choice. If "default" is white, you could run

`echo -ne '\e]11;#ffffff\e\\'`

Now since OP wants it in a bash script, I adapted the script by blueyed available here https://gist.github.com/blueyed/c8470c2aad3381c33ea3

```
#!/bin/sh
# Query a property from the terminal, e.g. background color.
#
# XTerm Operating System Commands
#     "ESC ] Ps;Pt ST"
#
# Source:
# Adapted from https://gist.github.com/blueyed/c8470c2aad3381c33ea3
# Posted at:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507337/how-to-determine-a-terminals-background-color#7767891
#

# save stty
oldstty=$(stty -g)

# Such that no input is needed for the read command:
stty raw -echo min 0 time 0

#11 for background color
printf "\033]11;?\033\\"

# xterm needs the sleep
sleep 0.1
read -r answer

# Change background color for #fff000 (as an example)
printf  "\033]11;#fff000\033\\"

# Do your stuff on yellow background
# Here for purpose of demonstration just sleep
sleep 1
#
#
#

# Restore background-color.
printf "\033$answer\\"

# Restore stty
stty $oldstty
```

You can then put your actual code in this script and modify the custom bg color (here yellow) and the sleep times etc. I tested it only on gnome-terminal.

Comment: Yeah I know, but different systems will have different default system colors, like in ubuntu is some sort of pink and in MacOS is white. I wanted to change to the system's default color.

Comment: I think the "default system color" is depending on the theme you use... If you're using that in a bash script, why not 1) save the current color with ```echo -ne "\e]11;?\a"``` 2) change the color with your command and 3) restore the color found in 1

Comment: Something like this? Doesen't seem to work, but probably it's wrong, thanks for the effort tho. 

`colorOriginal= echo -ne "\e]11;?\a"`
`echo -ne '\e]11;#17216F\e\\'`
`echo -ne '\e]11;${colorOriginal}\e\\'`

Comment: Your code has errors. Also it is not so easy to capture the output of the command ```echo -ne "\e]11;?\a"```. On the following link, the question was already answered and you'll find plenty of resources. There is also a script by blueyed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507337/how-to-determine-a-terminals-background-color#7767891 These commands are not working on all terminals, but ```gnome-terminal``` works. Also from the script you have to increase ```sleep``` value as many suggest.

Answer (score 3):

open the terminal, click on the hamburger menu (3 parallel line icon) and select `Preferences` then `Unnamed`. Select the `Colours` tab and select your required option from there.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to set the color back to default from a bash script, so it has to be from a command. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal supports resetting the colors via OSC 104/110/111:
`echo -ne '\e]111\e\\'`